# platform_details = platform.platform() NameError: name 'platform' is not defined

Tags: python

```
# importing module
import platform

# dictionary
info = {}

# platform details
platform_details = platform.platform()

# adding it to dictionary
info["platform details"] = platform_details

# system name
system_name = platform.system()

# adding it to dictionary
info["system name"] = system_name

# processor name
processor_name = platform.processor()

# adding it to dictionary
info["processor name"] = processor_name

# architectural detail
architecture_details = platform.architecture()

# adding it to dictionary
info["architectural detail"] = architecture_details

# printing the details
for i, j in info.items():
    print(i, " - ", j)
```

Comment: Your code runs without errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm enable to use platform libary. I already installed additionally Platform Libary using pip3 command